# Cannot safely convert passed over dtype of float64 for object dtyped data in column 1

Tags: pandas, csv

I am trying to read a csv file using panda, this is how the data looks while in the csv file,

```
Freq Level
2412 -84
2412 -85 
2412 -90
2412 -83
2412 -83
```

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

    x_data = pd.read_csv(data_path, encoding='utf7', dtype=float)
    print(x_data)
```

then I get the error "cannot safely convert passed use dtype of float64 for object dtyped data"

```
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   2057     def read(self, nrows=None):
   2058         try:
-> 2059             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
   2060         except StopIteration:
   2061             if self._first_chunk:

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_column_data()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens()

ValueError: cannot safely convert passed user dtype of float64 for object dtyped data in column 1
```

But if I try without the 'dtype = float' in code:

```
import pandas as pd

    x_data = pd.read_csv(data_path, encoding='utf7')
    print(x_data)
```

then I get the data but with ' ' in third column,

```
[[37710 2432 '-72']

[931 2412 '-73']

[10936 2412 '-66']

...

[48037 2437 '-73']

[84317 2467 '-67']

[33201 2427 '-79']]
```

and I guess '  ' is what causes error cause it makes pd reader converts the data from an object or str to float.

How can I get rid that ' ' for the third column data, auto float converted, and also not the error please?

Comment: Actually, can you figure out what value is causing the problem? If not, you can always coerce the column to numeric with `pd.to_numeric`.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried. An error came up say "arg must be a list , tuple, 1-d array, or Series", any?
And the value that causes the problem I am sure is the third coulmn '-72', '-73', '-66',...,'-73',' '-67'...

Answer (score 1):

The `encoding='utf7'` looks redundant to me but it's not the cause of your error. You are reading space-separated data while `read_csv` expects comma-separated by default.

Add `sep='\s+'`:

```
x_data = pd.read_csv(data_path, encoding='utf7', dtype=float, sep='\s+')
```

Comment: Thanks, and here is what I got:
[[37710 '2432,-72']
 [931 '2412,-73']
 [10936 '2412,-66']
 ...
 [48037 '2437,-73']
 [84317 '2467,-67']
 [33201 '2427,-79']] , I though the ' and , are supposed to disappear though..